# R specifying x-axis ticks for a line plot

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I have some time series with 200 values associated with 200 different times within an interval. After plotting the line plot, I would like to manually tell R to only show x axis ticks for some specific values I specify. Then, I would like to specify a different name, ie a date string, to be plotted at these ticks instead of the numerical value. I've looked at axis() but i'm having trouble putting this whole process together. I want the entire line graph to be plotted, not just the x labels i'm specifying.

For example:
If i have:
y = c(227, 342, 121, 275, 354, 999, 221, 475, 867, 347, 541)
x = c(1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 ,35, 40, 45, 50)

I want plot(x, y, "l") but with x axis ticks only at c(10, 30, 40). For these ticks, I would like to associate c("March", "June", "August") respectively and have these names as the labels for these three ticks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to resort to the manual axis creation. This can be done by (1) disabling the automatic axis creation (with `xaxt='n'` in the call to `plot`) and (2) make a custom call to the `axis` function.

Here is how I would proceed:

```
y = c(227, 342, 121, 275, 354, 999, 221, 475, 867, 347, 541)
x = c(1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 ,35, 40, 45, 50)
plot(x, y, "l", xaxt='n')
axis(1,at=c(10,30,40),labels=c("March", "June", "August"))
```

Resulting in the following plot:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I wanted. Just a followup, is their anyway to rotate the labels vertically? The dates are kind of long. Thanks

Comment: yop, you may use the option `las=2` in the call to `axis`.

Comment: And is there also a way to rotate labels by a custom angle, eg. 45 degrees?

Comment: @Wassermann in this case, you have to use `text`, as only this function can use the `srt` parameter to rotate a text. For the full example, replace the last line by this one: `text(x=c(10,30,40), y=rep(par('usr')[3],3), labels=c("March", "June", "August"), srt=45,xpd=T, pos=1, offset=1)`

Comment: Explanation on the above: `srt=45` means "rotate by 45 degrees the text" -- `y=rep(par('usr')[3],3)` replicates the bottommost coordinate of the plot three times, to know where to locate the labels -- `xpd=T` means that we can write outside of the graph box, on the axis part -- `pos=1` means that we will position the text to be _below_ the chosen coordinate, and `offset=1` means that we will offset the text by one character toward the bottom (because the text is tilted by 45 degrees, we need to free some space on top)

Comment: @Jealie thank you for an awsome answer! One thing I've changed was instead of removing the `axis()` line I set `labels=FALSE` argument which makes thicks on the x-axis still visible.